# Macro Practical Usage: anchor_lang::state

Tags: anchor

I was reading the anchor documentation and I noticed the [state](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/attr.state.html) attribute macro. Docs explains that it provides global state and mimics the Singleton Designed Pattern. This is exactly what I need to store program global configuration but I am not sure what this macro does under the hood. There are several questions that bothers me:

- What macro does under the hood?
- Where is global state stored (on which account)?
- Is it convenient for updates and how to update it? Program global configuration needs to be updated at some point and is this approach suitable for this case?

Comment: `anchor_lang::state` has been deprecated since v0.14.0. Its recommended now to use a PDA that is derived with static seed(s)

Comment: In general, if you wanna find out what the code looks like when you unwind macros, just run `anchor expand`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`anchor_lang::state` has been deprecated since v0.14.0. Its recommended now to use a PDA that is derived with static seed(s)